# Определение текущего пользователя Windows из под службы, запущенной от другого пользователя с минимальными привилегиями?

Tags: c#, .net, безопасность, .net-core, wmi

Пишу службу на .Net Core.
Предполагается что служба будет запускаться с технологической учетной записи с минимальными правами (максимально допустимый минимум).
Задача: Определить активного пользователя системы.
С помощью WMI можно получить текущего пользователя: wmic computersystem get username (SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem)
Беда в том что именно в случае когда служба будет запускаться с технологической учетной записи с минимальными правами SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem возвращает пустую строку. Если вместо технологической учетной записи запускать службу от администратора то все работает корректно.
Собственно вопрос: как получить текущего пользователя в моем случае?
Выслушаю все предложения и буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Требуйте прав побольше, раз они вам нужны. Или выдавайте их при установке.

Answer (score 0):

Домен пользователя: `Environment.UserDomainName`

Имя учетной записи пользователя: `Environment.UserName`

Comment: Это вернет владельца процесса, а требуется текущий активный пользователь системы.